# DICOM 3d display - Java 3D vs VTK

Tags: java, 3d, vtk, java-3d, medical-imaging

I'm going to work on implementing 3d display of dicom files and I'm wondering which technologies is easier to use: Java 3D or VTK?
I'm not very experienced programmer,but I've already created a DICOM viewer based on dcm4che open source library.

Any hints or experiences to share?

Comment: You can use Java 3D which is still actively maintained and there is already another DICOM viewer that has used it for years. Have a look at here for more information: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb

Answer (score 2):

Most of my 3D modeling is Optical Coherence Tomography data that tends to be rather large.  My experience has been a little backwards.  The project started as a C++ project using x64 VTK and Qt.  Folks in the lab weren't C++ people, so it got converted to Java which is used through Matlab, which the lab post-docs know.

Java VTK is really easy to use and has a lot of features, but I'm having some trouble with registering callback events for buttons and such with will be a deal breaker if it can't get resolved.  This problem might dramatically effect how the UI is done, so keep that in mind.

Most of the C++ examples tend to convert to Java really quickly (except callbacks >.< ) so there is a plethora of examples.  If you are going to use VTK, I highly recommend ["The VTK User's Guide" by Kitware, Inc (ISBN: 978-1-930934-23-8)](http://www.kitware.com/products/books/vtkguide.html), as it is an excellent overview of the API.

Good luck!